# Where can I buy/download a legal ISO copy of Windows home Server 2011?

Tags: windows-home-server

I'm Wondering where I can buy/download a copy of Windows Home Server 2011. I would like to install today.

I know I can go to eBay/Amazon and buy it. But it would be nice if I could do it today.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off topic on SU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/windows-home-server/get-it) says:

> ### Get a Windows Home Server 2011 computer
>
> Windows Home Server-based computers are available in a number of configurations and designs, and from a broad range of manufacturers. Availability varies by country and region. Please check with your retailer for local availability, or check out some of the recommended servers below.
>
> ### Building your own server
>
> If you're interested in purchasing software to build your own Windows Home Server system, please check with your software retailer for local availability.

Doesn't look like they sell it themselves *at all* and mostly want to bundle it with computers.

WHS is not available on http://www.microsoftstore.com/ at all.

Comment: I have already built my computer all i need is buy the software.It looks like I have to order it .What I pity they dont offer downloads.Silly no?

Comment: You can download WHS 2008 through Microsoft's Partner Downloads, but this exclusive for business partners. @user231465

Comment: It's also available for MSDN subscribers, but if you were a subscriber, you probably wouldn't ask (cc @slhck)

Comment: Given up and just bought a copy from amazon will get to me on tuesday. Oh well. I wish I was a msdn subscriber!